# C# Reading XML tags

Tags: c#, xml

I have xml file and I want to read the content of particular tags.
I know how to read the content of name tag but then I have address tag.
it goes like this:

```
<name>ANdrew</name>
<phone>456778</phone>
<address>Wooden street</address>
<name>John</name>
<phone>758465</phone>
<age>45</age>
<address>Steel street</address>
```

So address tag is always after name tag but between them there is a phone tag or maybe some other tags like age....
Now I need a loop which will go through whole file and collect all names and addresses. I don't know how to associate name and address in this loop....

Comment: also you can use conditional if/else. ex if node type is address then do something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have xml like this :

```
<Names>
<Name>
    <FirstName>John</FirstName>
    <LastName>Smith</LastName>
</Name>
<Name>
    <FirstName>James</FirstName>
    <LastName>White</LastName>
</Name>
```

You can use this code :

```
    XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml(myXmlString); // suppose that myXmlString contains "<Names>...</Names>"

XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/Names/Name");
foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
{
  string firstName = xn["FirstName"].InnerText;
  string lastName = xn["LastName"].InnerText;
  Console.WriteLine("Name: {0} {1}", firstName, lastName);
}
```

Comment: OK I get it, it lookes nice, BUT will it work if i dont have parent tags in my xml ? So I dont have Names and then name. The tags in xml file are just like I presented no parent tags..

Comment: Use xml.Load instead of LoadXml. I got "Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1." error when tried to load the xml using LoadXml method.

Answer (score 2):

You can query it with Linq to XML (although this xml should be formatted differently):

```
string xml = @"<Names>
                   <name>ANdrew</name>
                   <phone>456778</phone>
                   <address>Wooden street</address>
                   <name>John</name>
                   <phone>758465</phone>
                   <age>45</age>
                   <address>Steel street</address>
               </Names>";

XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var names = doc.Root.Elements("name").Select(n => n.Value);
var addresses = doc.Root.Elements("address").Select( a => a.Value);

var results = names.Zip(addresses, (name, address) => name + " has the following address: " + address);

foreach (var r in results)
    Console.WriteLine(r);  // ANdrew has the following address: Wooden street
                           // John has the following address: Steel street
```

Answer (score 1):

Use XPath to select the nodes that you need

```
var nodes = document.SelectNodes("//root/name")
```

And you can do the same for address then iterate over the node collections

Comment: OK, so I will have all names in var nodes and all addresses in var nodes2 but how I will know which address belongs to which name ?

Answer (score 0):

I read xml docs via DataSet or collection of data tables.

`string xmlPath = "C:\blabla.xml";
StreamReader streamRead = new StreamReader(xmlPath)
byte[] fullByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(streamRead.ReadToEnd());
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream(fullByte);
dataSet.ReadXml(mStream);`

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ to XML you could select the `name` elements and then access `ElementsAfterSelf("address").First()` e.g.

```
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(@"<root><name>ANdrew</name>
<phone>456778</phone>
<address>Wooden street</address>
<name>John</name>
<phone>758465</phone>
<age>45</age>
<address>Steel street</address>
</root>");
            foreach (XElement name in doc.Root.Elements("name"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", (string)name, (string)name.ElementsAfterSelf("address").First());
            }
```

Of course if you have an XML file use `XDocument.Load("input.xml")` instead of `Parse`.